# Is it possible to craft items that dominate their users when they are activated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, curses

I am getting wondrous item creation feat and i wanted to know if i could make trapped items that give me control of those who loot my items upon being activated by tying dominate person spell to the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Will [*suggestion*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/suggestion/) or [*charm monster*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-monster/) do instead?

The creator of a magic item may be able to increase its price by +200 gp to make a permanent magic item an [intelligent item](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/artifactsAndOthers/intelligentItems.html#intelligent-items)—granting the magic item an Intelligence score of 11, empathy, and senses with ranges of 30 ft.—and another +500 gp to grant the intelligent item speech.<sup>1</sup> Unlike *Pathfinder*'s predecessor, creating an intelligent item has *no* minimum caster level. (Intelligent items in *D&D 3.5* require caster level 15.)

Thus, assuming the GM allows a creator to create intelligent items *and* assuming the DM allows the creator to pick the intelligent item's alignment (which in this case I suspect will correspond to the creator's alignment) *and* assuming the DM allows the creator to dictate the intelligent item's personality (which in this case I suspect the creator will opt for the intelligent item to possess an unwavering loyalty to its creator), *then* the creator need only add +6,000 gp to the intelligent item's price so that it can cast 1/day the spell *suggestion* or +11,200 gp for 1/day the spell *charm monster*; both spells require the caster to speak to the subject, making creating yammering intelligent items, unfortunately, a necessity.<sup>2</sup> A thief that liberates the intelligent item from its creator should see that fiercely loyal intelligent item employ its spell on the thief.<sup>3</sup>

(As printed an intelligent item can't be created so that it can use the spell [*dominate monster*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dominate-monster/)—the spell's level is too high. Nonetheless, a generous GM could expand the table; my calculations put a 1/day *dominate monster* effect as having a price of +61,200 gp.)

### A word of caution

On Intelligent Items says, "Unlike most magic items, intelligent items can activate their own powers without waiting for a command word from their owner. Intelligent items act during their owner’s turn in the initiative order." This means a GM probably should—or soon will—have some kind of limit on the creation of intelligent items lest creators mass produce intelligent items and upset the game's already precarious balance. Creators that make *every* magical gewgaw—from the tops of their *[headbands of vast intellect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-vast-intelligence) +6* to the bottoms of their [*boots of speed*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/boots-of-speed/)—into intelligent items with the ability to cast spells will, if they take their turns, take *all* of their fiercely loyal intelligent magic items' turns, also. That's bad for everyone.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Pick Common.
<sup>**2**</sup> I urge dictating that the intelligent item have the personality trait laconic.
<sup>**3**</sup> Discuss proper behavior in case of thieves with the intelligent item beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

### [A Crystal Hypnosis Ball](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic-items/cursed-items/#TOC-Crystal-Hypnosis-Ball)

This crystal ball is created using Dominate Person, False Vision, and Scrying. See the link for details, but when used it gives a false vision and the user must pass a DC 19 Will save or have a [Suggestion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/suggestion) implanted in their mind. It's not quite the same as Dominate Person, but the user doesn't realise what they're looking at is fake, so they're likely to keep using it. Each successive use is likely to bring them further under your control.